# Html is not loading in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am loading html from website using following way

```
     -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
//CategoriesParser *parser=[[CategoriesParser alloc]init];
//[parser setDelegate:self];
//[parser startParsing:xmlData];

NSString *str=@"<html><head></head><body>";

NSString* newStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData

                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

 newStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body>%@</body></html>",newStr];


[webView loadHTMLString:newStr baseURL:nil];
```

}

but unfortunately it is showing html code on webview as

```
  <p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-family: helvetica; font-size: small;">The UAE manages what some Arab cities fail to achieve;
```

etc

so please help what i am doing wrong by loading html string in webview

Comment: If your newStr has any symbols like (< or >) it may not show the string on webview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me

```
-(void)loadHTML{

NSMutableString *html  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body>%@</body></html>",@"Hi"]; 
[self.tpWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

}